# How to compare same Windows application running on separate machines?

Tags: windows

What is a good way to compare a running application on Windows machine A with the same application on Windows machine B?

This is a single process application, fairly small, under 40 megabytes private bytes. It works properly on more than one machine but does not work on machine A. What I would like, is to analyse the **difference** in how it runs on the two machines, to try find the problem on machine A.

I have tried [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) but that shows thousands of events for the process, mostly registry events. Should I use filters or look for something specific in Process Monitor? What is a good way to compare the process on two machines?

The application is a bar code reader. The driver and application have been uninstalled and reinstalled on machine A but somehow the same problem still appears. The application worked and was used regularly on machine A for more than year and stopped recently. I think there was an Windows update after it last worked.

Comment: Perhaps this could be helpful: https://github.com/patraulea/LogDiff

Comment: I'll give it a try @GiaRui

Comment: Perhaps also other tools of the sysinternals-suite might be helpful. E.g dbgview, ProcessExplorer, SystemMonitor, VMmap etc.